# Clojure read-string

Tags: clojure

(read-string "01") returns 1.

In fact read-string from "01" to "07" returns the correct answer. But while we do (read-string "08") it throws an error:

> NumberFormatException Invalid number: 08  clojure.lang.LispReader.readNumber (LispReader.java:330).

Can anyone plese help me to figure out why?"

Comment: This question is about the read-string function, which is slightly more specific than the question it's marked as a duplicate of. read-string has important security considerations that are worth noting. Mostly that it's **totally unsafe** for use on user supplied input

Answer (score 5):

If the string starts with a 0, then the number is read as an octal number:
https://www.ascii.cl/conversion.htm

Thus, the table below, with some sample conversions:

- 01 -> 1
- 02 -> 2
- 0117 -> 79
- 0200 -> 128
- 08 -> invalid

Answer (score 4):

If you had kept going you may have seen:

```
> (read-string "010")
8
```

Literal numbers beginning with `0` are taken to be octal (base 8).  Hence the digit `8` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to leading zeros indicating octal you can specify the base with XrNNN where X is the base you want:

In octal:

```
user> 010
8
```

Or specify a base:

```
user> 8r010
8
user> 2r010
2
user> 16r010
16
user> 17r010
17
```

Or you can use the suffix `N` to read a bigint with either the leading zero or not

```
user> 010N
8N
user> 10N
10N
```

Though this does not work with the radix prefix:

```
user> 2r1010N
NumberFormatException For input string: "1010N"
```

---

And of course **READ STRING IS TOTALLY UNSAFE BY DEFAULT**

```
user> #=(slurp "http://example.com")
"<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" />\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: \"Open Sans\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 50px;\n        background-color: #fff;\n        border-radius: 1em;\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        body {\n            background-color: #fff;\n        }\n        div {\n            width: auto;\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            border-radius: 0;\n            padding: 1em;\n        }\n    }\n    </style>    \n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>\n    <p><a href=\"http://www.iana.org/domains/example\">More information...</a></p>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

`read-string` must **never be used on untrusted imput** and your should
in almost all cases **always prefer clojure.edn/read-string**

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string "2r1010")
10
```

There exists a magic incantation to turn off read evaluation, as a global state, that other libraries could turn back on without telling you, so never depend on that, use clojure.edn/read-string in all cases.

Yes i have broken into a real production website using read string as part of an authorized professional security penetration test.